# How to update source data for each iteration

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have an array of objects as following

```js
const cat = ['Admin', 'Tax', 'Depriciation', 'Amortization', 'Fee', 'Interest'];

//build the src data structure;
const src = cat.map((d, i) => {
    return {
        cat: d,
        year: null,
        val: null
    };
});
console.log(src);

//yr for iteration
const yr = [2020, 2021, 2022];
```

I want to run a `for` loop on `src` and write a script in such a way that I end up with at least 3 sets of the array of objects one for each year. My desired output is following

```
[
{cat: 'Admin', year: 2020, val: someProgrammaticValue};
{cat: 'Tax', year: 2020, val: someProgrammaticValue};
........................................
{cat: 'Interest', year: 2020, val: someProgrammaticValue}
]



[
{cat: 'Admin', year: 2021, val: someProgrammaticValue};
{cat: 'Tax', year: 2021, val: someProgrammaticValue};
.........................................
{cat: 'Interest', year: 2021, val: someProgrammaticValue}
]


[
{cat: 'Admin', year: 2022, val: someProgrammaticValue};
{cat: 'Tax', year: 2022, val: someProgrammaticValue};
.........................................
{cat: 'Interest', year: 2022, val: someProgrammaticValue}
]
```

To achieve this, I tried using `setInterval` in conjunction with `clearInterval` but I must not have done it correctly which is why it is probably not doing the job.

```js
const cat = ['Admin', 'Tax', 'Depriciation', 'Amortization', 'Fee', 'Interest'];

//build the src data structure;
const src = cat.map((d, i) => {
    return {
        cat: d,
        year: null,
        val: null
    };
});
//console.log(src);

//yr for iteration
const yr = [2020, 2021, 2022];

for (let i = 0; i < yr.length; i++) {
    const iv = setInterval(
        function() {
            src.map(a => { a.year = yr[i], a.val = Math.random() * 500; });
            console.log(src, i);
            if (i <= yr.length) { clearInterval(iv) };
        }, 1000
    )

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prod3.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am getting this in chrome and I don't know where it is going wrong.

[image: Chrome Output]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `setInternal` or `setTimeout` are needed. seems like you can accomplish the result using `Array.map`?

Since the number of arrays desired equals the length of the `yr` array, mapping over it will create all the necessary arrays. Then you can key into individual ones like `result[0]` to get `2020` array

```js
const cat = ['Admin', 'Tax', 'Depriciation', 'Amortization', 'Fee', 'Interest'];

//yr for iteration
const yr = [2020, 2021, 2022];

const result = yr.map(y => {
  return cat.map(d => {
    return {
      cat: d,
      year: y,
      val: Math.random()
    }
  });
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I am not focused on how to transform the entire dataset at once with all the iterations. Though, thanks for this. I want to retrieve the state of the data for each iteration cause I am trying to see if I can pass on each state (from each iteration) of the data to create viz using d3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as the other person said setInterval isn't needed. But that doesn't explain why your code didn't work properly.

What is happening is that in the browser console when you log an object only the top level properties are stored. That is if you log the object `{a:1,b:{c:2}}` the console only stores a, and that b is an object.

```
let x = {a:1,b:{c:2}};
console.log(x);
x.b.c = 3;
```

Now if you go to the console and expand property b you can see that it shows 3, even though it was 2 at the time of logging. I assume this shallow logging is done for performance reasons.

And the final detail is that arrays are treated like objects here, that is why your code has this behavior.